# ubuntu 14.04 disk full

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

when i run df -h on my ubuntu 14.04 laptop i see the following:

```
   pdp2907@pdp2907-Satellite-C655:~$ df -h
   Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
   udev                         933M  4.0K  933M   1% /dev
   tmpfs                        189M  1.1M  188M   1% /run
   dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  228G  215G  1.1G 100% /
   none                         4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
   none                         5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
   none                         943M   11M  933M   2% /run/shm
   none                         100M   36K  100M   1% /run/user
  /dev/sda1                    236M   44M  180M  20% /boot
```

the /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root is full.

how do i correct the problem please.?

thanx for all your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know what data is on it. So far I assume you have a whole OS in / only. What you can do is, for example, move some content to anoter volume (disk) and either mount it or make a symbolic link. I personally place /usr to a separate volume, and my /opt is a link. Then the root partition does not need to be so huge. But in your case the root has over 200 Gb what seems a bit more than the OS only :). Explore the files over there, perhaps you also find some movies if the user's home directories are also there...

```
find / -size +100M
```

The command above might be helpful to search for files over 100 Mb size (normally should not appear in root filesystem)

Comment: thanx. worked like magic. some large csv file was stored in /trash/local

Answer (score 1):

In order to free up disk space in dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root you can remove cached files with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

You still can free up more space by uninstalling packages that are not required anymore:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: did . however did not change much. however thanx for your help